# Is it possible to remove white background in asp.menu dynamic sub menu and make it transparent

Tags: asp.net, css, menu, transparent

I am using the asp.menu conrol of asp.net 3.5. I want the sub menu to be completely transperant, with no background at all and only text being displayed. Is it possible?

I tried to make the background transperant in css for primaryDynamicMenuItem and primaryDynamicMenu class but it is displaying white back ground in IE8.
I also tried applying opacity like

filter: alpha(opacity=50);

filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(Color='#FFFFFF');

filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50);

-moz-opacity:0.5;

opacity:0.5;

Also when I check the source at browser

```
.ctl00_Menu_0 { *background-color:white;*visibility:hidden;display:none;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px; }

.ctl00_Menu_1 { text-decoration:none; }...
```

Here background color is set to white by .NET, how to remove this and make this transparent
How to remove white back ground and make asp.menu fully transperant.

Comment: It has to work in both IE6 and later versions, so I applied both filter and _filter, still it is not working

Comment: checkout the z-index as described in my answer below...

Comment: I have set the z-index of the div containing menu to 2000 and menu itself to 100. Still it is not working. Also in primaryDynamicMenu and primaryDynamicMenuItem z-index is set to 100. Do I need to still increase the index?

Comment: that depends on the index of the content... set the content index very low and the menu index very high...

Answer (score 0):

Several aspects:

Are you sure this IE8 and not IE6 ? check [this out](http://www.goldmandesign.com/blog/tips/aspnet-drop-down-menu-control-white-rounded-corner-issue-fix) - basically for IE6 `filter` needs to be `_filter` .

Another point is the `z-index`... often the problem is in the `z-index`... i.e. set the `z-index` of the menu to a high value and that of the content to a low value...

Answer (score 0):

After trying every thing, I had to go for CSSAdapters for the menu, for it to work in all browsers.